# Fast partial image bulge effect

Tags: java, android, image-processing, libgdx

I'm writing a small `libGdx` application that may be able to distort a face simulating hits (something similar to `FaceSmash`), but can't find what kind of filter should I apply, neither info about math algorithms to achieve something like a bulge effect.

I've started from SphereFilter on

http://www.jhlabs.com/

but definitely the effect is not what I'm looking for.

I'm aware of

[Image Warping - Bulge Effect Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055625/image-warping-bulge-effect-algorithm)

and

[How to warp images in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237924/how-to-warp-images-in-android)

I've achieved to 'translate' the bulge effect mentioned on the first thread, but is relatively slow, and can't find the way to create bulges in a region, not the whole image.

The warp sample on `Api demos` (2nd thread) is really fast, and changes only part of the image, but is not exactly a bulge effect, and my image processing maths are far from understanding how could I modify the algorithm to change the effect.

I can feel I'm in the right direction, but I'm totally stuck. Any idea of how any of these algorithms could be modified in order to get 'local' bulges inside the image?

**EDIT**

Just found this thread.-

[How can you apply distortions to a UIImage using OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886843/how-can-you-apply-distortions-to-a-uiimage-using-opengl-es)

Not android, but looks promising. I'll give a try to OpenGL shaders and share (hopefully) a solution for my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I managed to find a solution using OpenGL `shaders` based on [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework

The resulting fragment shader looks like this.-

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float aspectRatio;
uniform vec2 center;
uniform float radius;
uniform float scale;

void main() 
{  
    vec2 textureCoordinateToUse = vec2(v_texCoords.x, (v_texCoords.y * aspectRatio + center.y - center.y * aspectRatio));
    float dist = distance(center, textureCoordinateToUse);
    textureCoordinateToUse = v_texCoords;
    if (dist < radius)
    {
        textureCoordinateToUse -= center;
        float percent = 1.0 - ((radius - dist) / radius) * scale;
        percent = percent * percent;
        textureCoordinateToUse = textureCoordinateToUse * percent;
        textureCoordinateToUse += center;
    }
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, textureCoordinateToUse);
}
```

Hope someone find it helpful.

Comment: i can't able to understand clearly what you want to say.. Can you help me more? i stuck in problem for last few week.. i am trying to make image effect like [fatbooth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piviandco.fatbooth&hl=en).. i know this is not right way how stack overflow work but can you plz help me...